# Craft folder deployment outside public folder

Tags: deployment

I would like to commit my craft project to bitbucket en deploy it with the help of Deploybot.

The plan is to put the templates (in craft folder) and public assets (public folder) under version control and deploy it with Deploybot. But how do i get the files published into the right directories on the live/staging server.

My craft folder is outside the public root and the public files/assets are inside the public root. So i have two source directories and two destination directories, and this isn't an option with Deploybot. Is there someone with the same setup and a solution?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Who is your host?

Comment: standard shared hosting with directadmin as controlpanel

Comment: Will you be deploying via FTP? If so when you setup your FTP credentials see if you can have access to the parent folder of `public`.  This way you can publish to that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dennis,

I use deploybot with Craft and easily deploy. So on your server settings you'll have this:

name: your site name

Host: ip address or domain.com

port: 22 or similar

destination path: /path/to/site_username/

in the destination path set it to be just above public and then you'll deploy /site_username/craft and site_username/pubic

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but isn't this giving you problems with the already excisting public folder? Or is it just deploying the contents of the public folder and not replacing the folder itself.

Deploybot support suggests two server environments leading to the same destination server and each connected to the same branch but with a different source path. 

So the public and the craft deployment run in seperate environments but lead to the same server but with a different destination and sourcepath.

Comment: @Dennis Deployment sends files into the already existing folder. No problems. Deploybots suggestion of two server environments seems overly complicated especially since what I'm doing already just works.